# How can i split/divide my native screen (home screen) in android programatically?

Tags: android, split, grid, homescreen, divide

I have a problem and i want to share you. How can i split/divide my native screen (home screen) by drawing grid or etc. in android programatically? Do you have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is a "native screen"?

Comment: Any idea how to go about this? @CommonsWare

Comment: @TheLuminor: I suggest that you post your own question, that is **much more descriptive** about the nature of your problem.